# Why is some blackout on objects here?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, unity3d-shaders

[image: Example image]

Hello I have a problem. I'm using 2dToolkit and when I creating objects that don't overlap they're creating some shadow at the junction of two objects. You can see it's on top rects. When I use similar sprites it doesn't appear. It's appear only when I use different sprites (textures).

Comment: I'd claim its an optical illusion .. since the two colors are different of course you will somewhere have a hard line .. I think it only appears to have a "shadow" ... [this I made with paint](https://imgur.com/6uiuP6g) and just shows the same behavior ;)